# Can I apply attributes to object fields dynamically?

Tags: .net, attributes, projects-and-solutions, solution, code-cleanup

I am working on a project, that will serialize/store objects in CSV files. (Yes I am aware that this is not the best practice, but it's a must.)

I'm trying to keep my solution clean, so I have multiple projects inside the solution, one of them is a library project that contains the storage/serialization methods. This project has a reference to CSVhelper, a 3rd party library that I'ld like to use to do the CSV operations.

**In project A**

```
foo myobject = new foo(x,y,z);
B.WriteToCsv(myobject);
```

**In project B (my lib, referencing csvhelper)**

```
public static WriteToCsv(foo myobject); // csvhelper would do the work
```

However, Csvhelper requires certain attributes set on my foo object before it can operate on it.

I am trying to avoid applying these attributes in my foo object class definition file, instead I prefer to apply these attributes dynamically inside project B.

My question is, is it possible to apply attributes later on, dynamically? The whole point is to keep my project clean as possible, but I feel like this would complicate things even more. Is this a bad idea, or is there a common solution for this issue?

---

Update on request, with example:

My foo object definition:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string a;
    public string b;
    public int c;
}
```

CsvHelper requires attributes on the fields like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [CsvColumn(Name = "a", FieldIndex = 1)]
    public string a;
    [CsvColumn(Name = "b", FieldIndex = 2)]
    public string b;
    [CsvColumn(Name = "c", FieldIndex = 3)]
    public int c;
}
```

In order to keep my code clean, I want to avoid adding these attributes here, because I want to keep all code related to storing/serializing in my separate library. (Project B)

Comment: By "attributes" do you mean properties, or attributes in the .NET sense, e.g. `[Serializable]`? It would really help if you'd provide a short but complete example.

Comment: @JonSkeet Updated. I mean attributes in .NET sense, yes. [XYZ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. In your case - No.

You can hypothetically add attributes dynamically but this requires quite different approach to reflection. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171819.aspx
I doubt third party library supports this.

I'd prefer to associate types/objects with some kind of configuration when flexibility is needed.
If you need to attach some values to the object consider [ConditionalWeakTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757(v=vs.110).aspx).

But all these variants unfortunately cannot be used in your situation.

If you need to separate concerns just create DTOs with correctly applied attributes and use some kind of mapper (e.g. [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)) to easily convert entities.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot bolt on attributes like [XYZ] onto existing compiled code, it has to be present at compile time.

A typical method for a class library to handle such things is that it may have an overload that takes in a data structure containing the metadata, and another overload that extracts the metadata from attributes. If there are no such overloads in this class library, you're out of luck.

You *could* generate descendant classes at runtime, if the classes allow for inheritance, and in this case you could add whatever attributes you see fit. Depending on the security model and the existing classes this may or may not be an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

The common pattern for this is for the "helper" utility to use a system of either Attributes or Resolvers or both. A good example of this is ProtoBuf. The pattern works like this;

1. The caller passes in an interface pointer to a Resolver method.
2. The helper function calls the Resolver for the Type its processing, which can return specific information about how to handle the Type.
3. If no Resolver interface is passed or the call to Resolver fails to provide useful information the Helper falls back onto Attributes to see if they provide the neccessary information.

This is a very neat system bridging the SOLID world and the earlier Attribute based style of programming.